# Given a date and a duration, calculate the future date

Tags: c++, datetime

The question is basically like this:
Given year, month, day and duration, calculate the future date based on given data and duration. The given date guarantees to be after 1900-01-01, and the duration k is between [0, 10000].

For example:
Input:
2016 10 1 100(meaning given 2016-10-1, what is the future date after 100 days)
Output:
2017-01-09

Another example:
Input:
2017 1 1 10
Output:
2017-01-11

I have done my solution, but it is trivial and ugly. The most frustrating part is **line 44 - 47**, where I have to handle special cases on month and year. I feel like this special and trivial handling is due to my design of calculating month, but I cannot figure out a more universal/clear solution except for current solution.

Love to hear your advice! Thank you!

Code with line indication and better format fyi : https://paste.ubuntu.com/24765263/

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>
using namespace std; // I know global namespace is bad practice. Just to save time.


int getMonthDays(int y, int m){
    unordered_map <int, int >daysMap = {{1,31}, {2,28}, {3,31}, {4,30}, {5,31}, {6,30}, {7,31}, {8,31}, {9,30}, {10,31}, {11,30}, {0,31}};
    if (m == 2){
        if (y % 400 ==0 || (y % 100 != 0&& y % 4 == 0)){
            return 29;
        }
        else{
            return 28;
        }
    }
    else{
        return daysMap[m];
    }
}

int main (){

    int year, month, day, duration;
    cin >> year >> month >> day >> duration;

    int res_year;
    string res_month, res_day;

    int days = getMonthDays(year, month) - day;
    while ( days < duration ){
        month++;
        if(days + getMonthDays(year + month/12, (month - 12 * (month/13))% 12) > duration){
            break;
        }
        else{
            days += getMonthDays(year + month/12, (month - 12 * (month/13))% 12);
        }

    }

    res_year = year + month / 12 ;
    res_month = (month - 12 * (month/13))% 12 >= 10 ? to_string((month - 12 * (month/13))% 12) : "0" + to_string((month - 12 * (month/13))% 12);
    if (res_month == "00"){
        res_month = "12"; // dont have set month "12", so if get month as "00", convert it to "12"
        res_year -= 1; // if the result month is "12", year minus 1 coz Month December is still in this year.
    }

    if (duration - days > 0 ){
        if (duration - days >= 10){
            res_day = to_string(duration - days);
        }
        else{
            res_day = "0" + to_string(duration - days);
        }
    }
    else{
        res_day = to_string(day + duration);
    }
    cout << res_year << "-" << res_month << "-" << res_day;

}
```

Comment: This is common interview type question. I think you choose the wrong technique to solve this. When doing date/time and manipulating: Convert to seconds (an epoch time). Do your manipulation then convert back into Gregorian from there.

Comment: @LokiAstari, I believe I found more or less C++ way of outputting result of `std::chrono::xxx_clock::now()`. It might be worth updating the answer you've given long ago if you think the approach is good.

Comment: For convenience you can also take a look at [Hinnant's Date library](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date) to simplify the work for you.

Comment: @coincoin, I already mentioned it in the review :) I didn't want to deal with the license so I implemented some stuff by hand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is quite tricky problem to get right. As Loki said, we need to convert it to seconds after epoch. But doing so is not trivial...

### Standard approach:

Well, not really standard, but in my opinion one should use `std::chrono` in this case. Some stuff is done in a roundabout way, but I don't think it is a huge problem. Howard Hinnant has written a library for it, but in case the license isn't acceptable, I'll reimplement some functionality by hand.

#### output `std::time_point`:

The first issue is outputting a `std::time_point`. The problem with it is that it doesn't have `operator<<` overload for streams. The only way possible to deal with this is to implement our own:

Necessary links:

- [`std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/system_clock/to_time_t) (system clock is just example).
- [`std::localtime()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/localtime)
- [`std::put_time()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/put_time)
- [`std::mktime()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/mktime)

The only ways to print time are either `std::ctime()` and `std::put_time()` (not counting the "implement by hand" approach). So let's follow the thread and find its end and test it:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <iomanip>

template <typename Clock, typename Duration>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const std::chrono::time_point<Clock, Duration>& timep)
{
    auto converted_timep = Clock::to_time_t(timep);
    os << std::put_time(std::localtime(&converted_timep), "%Y %b %d %H:%M:%S");
    return os;
}

int main()
{
    auto now = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    std::cout << now;

    return 0;
}
```

Output: `2017 Jun 04 12:07:48`.

The only problem with implementation is that it can't be used from multiple threads, since `std::localtime()` returns pointer to static variable. The format could be mutable by some function, but I wouldn't care about it at this point.

Since we can manipulate `std::chrono::time_point`, and `std::chrono::duration`, let's use everything we have:

**convert given date to `std::chrono::time_point<system_clock>`:**

A good news, at last! From `std::mktime()`:

> Converts local calendar time to a time since epoch as a `time_t` object. **`time->tm_wday` and `time->tm_yday` are ignored**. The values in `time` are permitted to be outside their normal ranges.

Hooray! So we can just fill in the `std::tm` structure with year, month, and day since January 1 and we are done!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <iomanip>

template <typename Clock, typename Duration>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const std::chrono::time_point<Clock, Duration>& timep)
{
    auto converted_timep = Clock::to_time_t(timep);
    os << std::put_time(std::localtime(&converted_timep), "%Y %b %d %H:%M:%S");
    return os;
}

auto convert_to_timepoint(int years, int months, int days)
{
    //perform checks, do division, modulus and stuff...
    years -= 1900; //epoch
    std::tm date = {};
    date.tm_year = years;
    date.tm_mon = months;
    date.tm_mday = days;

    return std::chrono::system_clock::from_time_t(std::mktime(&date));
}

int main()
{
    auto now = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    std::cout << now << '\n';

    std::cout << "calling convert_to_timepoint:\n";
    auto date = convert_to_timepoint(1991, 0, 23);
    std::cout << date;

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
2017 Jun 04 13:08:49
calling convert_to_timepoint:
1991 Jan 23 00:00:00
```

Now the easy stuff, add the given number of days:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <iomanip>

template <typename Clock, typename Duration>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const std::chrono::time_point<Clock, Duration>& timep)
{
    auto converted_timep = Clock::to_time_t(timep);
    os << std::put_time(std::localtime(&converted_timep), "%Y %b %d %H:%M:%S");
    return os;
}

auto convert_to_timepoint(int years, int months, int days)
{
    years -= 1900; //epoch
    std::tm date = {};
    date.tm_year = years;
    date.tm_mon = months;
    date.tm_mday = days;

    return std::chrono::system_clock::from_time_t(std::mktime(&date));
}

template <typename Clock, typename Duration>
auto add_days(const std::chrono::time_point<Clock, Duration>& timepoint, int days_to_add)
{
    constexpr std::time_t seconds_in_day = 60 * 60 * 24;
    //                                     mm   hh   dd

    std::time_t days = seconds_in_day * days_to_add;
    auto date = Clock::to_time_t(timepoint);
    return Clock::from_time_t(date + days);
}

int main()
{
    auto now = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    std::cout << now << '\n';

    std::cout << "calling convert_to_timepoint with 1991 0 23 (1991 Jan 23):\n";
    auto date = convert_to_timepoint(1991, 0, 23);
    std::cout << date << '\n';

    std::cout << "10 day later (1991 Feb 02):\n" << add_days(date, 10);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
2017 Jun 04 13:21:29
calling convert_to_timepoint with 1991 0 23 (1991 Jan 23):
1991 Jan 23 00:00:00
10 day later (1991 Feb 02):
1991 Feb 02 00:00:00
```

I left the `convert_to_timepoint()` so that it would be reusable on its own, but if needed it can be fused with `add_days()`.

### Some thoughts:

- `using namespace std;` rarely buys anything, but opens a chance for errors.
- standard library has a solution most of the time
- modularity is important. Breaking functions into logical pieces makes it very easy to quickly prototype, adjust, mix'n'match.

### Conclusion:

In this kind of problem, it is very dangerous try to implement by hand, since there are lots of edge cases. As a result, the problem given was rather a test of knowledge of standard library.

Comment: The date is calculated using [this site](https://www.timeanddate.com/calendar/?year=1990&country=1).

Comment: Thank very much for your explanation! @Incomputable  Really appreciated!!

Comment: @JenifferPan, you're welcome! It's still worth checking out Howard's library, since he was leading `<chrono>`s development.